# spring boot application war deployment in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: spring-boot

My colleague and me developed simple spring boot application and deployed (war file) in AWS Beanstalk. It is not worked properly.My first 
page(loginpage.jsp-Get mapping) loaded perfectly in AWS. After submitting credentials my second page(Mainpage.jsp - Post mapping)
does not loaded. It shows internal server error=500 only. But we deployed on Tomcat server(local) all pages (Request and Response) loaded perfectly.
we did not added any cloud dependency in Pom.xml. Please help us...

This is our 
     [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIzZ2.png).
This is our 
     [Pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRMg.png).

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: See my error message and dependencies.